# Trigger con multiples condiciones

Tags: sql, plsql, trigger, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio, pero me estado costando avanzar:

Queremos crear los siguientes disparadores:

- Un disparador llamado TRIG_EMPLEADOS que salte al insertar o actualizar en la tabla N_EMPLEADOS para que no nos deje insertar o actualizar si se produce uno de los siguientes casos:

o La fecha de alta debe ser menor que la fecha del sistema.

o El sexo solo puede tener valor H o M, en mayúsculas

o La provincia debe ser CIUDAD REAL, CUENCA, GUADALAJARA, TOLEDO o ALBACETE, en
mayúsculas

Se lanzará una excepción (RAISEE_APPLICATION_ERROR), mediante la cual el registro no se inserte y visualice el mensaje adecuado.

Os dejo el codigo que llevo:

```
-- EJERCICIO 4
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_EMPLEADOS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON N_EMPLEADOS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF :NEW.FECHA_ALTA > SYSDATE THEN
        RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'LA FECHA DEBE SER SUPERIOR AL DIA ACTUAL');
    END IF;

    IF UPPER(:NEW.SEXO) <> 'H' OR UPPER(:NEW.SEXO) <> 'M' THEN
        RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'EL SEXO DEBE SER H - M EN MAYUSCULAS');
    END IF;

    IF UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'CIUDAD REAL' OR 
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'CUENCA' OR
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'GUADALAJARA' OR
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'TOLEDO' OR 
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'ALBACETE' THEN
        RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'LA PROVINCIA DEBE ESTAR EN CASTILLA LA MANCHA');
    END IF;

END;
```

El caso es que me compila el trigger, pero se queja:

```
Trigger TRIG_EMPLEADOS compilado

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/9       PLS-00201: identifier 'RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR' must be declared
3/9       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
7/9       PLS-00201: identifier 'RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR' must be declared
7/9       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
15/9      PLS-00201: identifier 'RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR' must be declared
15/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Errores: comprobar log de compilador
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error que arroja o en qué necesitas ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está quejando de que `RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR` no está declarado, con lo cual, tienes que añadir al principio una seccion `DECLARE` de una `EXCEPTION` y llamarlas en los casos que quieras:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_EMPLEADOS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON N_EMPLEADOS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    MAYOR_FECHA EXCEPTION;
    DISTINTO_SEXO EXCEPTION;
    PROVINCIA_DISTINTA EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.FECHA_ALTA > SYSDATE THEN
        RAISE MAYOR_FECHA;
    END IF;

    IF UPPER(:NEW.SEXO) <> 'H' OR UPPER(:NEW.SEXO) <> 'M' THEN
        RAISE DISTINTO_SEXO;
    END IF;

    IF UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'CIUDAD REAL' OR 
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'CUENCA' OR
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'GUADALAJARA' OR
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'TOLEDO' OR 
       UPPER(:NEW.PROVINCIA) <> 'ALBACETE' THEN
        RAISE PROVINCIA DISTINTA;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN MAYOR_FECHA THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LA FECHA DEBE SER SUPERIOR AL DIA ACTUAL');
    WHEN DISTINTO_SEXO THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EL SEXO DEBE SER H - M EN MAYUSCULAS');
    WHEN PROVINCIA_DISTINTA THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LA PROVINCIA DEBE ESTAR EN CASTILLA LA MANCHA');   
END;
```